# How to Create a Mezzanine menu including children elements of current page

Tags: django, django-templates, mezzanine

I want to create a Menu that handles information about the current page and their siblings for example, if I have the following tree:

[image]

If I am in page `Child 1` my menu should only display `Page 1` and the `children 1-3`

This can be achieved with the following code:

```
<a href="{{ page.parent.get_absolute_url }}">{{ page.parent.title }}</a>

<ul>
    {% page_menu page.parent %}
</ul>
```

The problem I have is that I would like to display the `Grand Child 1 and 2` if I am located in Child 2. How can I do that?

I tried the following:

```
<ul>
{% for page in branch_page %}
    {% if page.is_current_sibling %}
     <li><a href="{{ page.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ page.title }}</a>
          {% if page.is_current_or_ascendant %}
             {% page_menu page %}
          {% endif %}  
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But it doesn't work and it does not display any error, how can I do this in another way?

Answer (score 1):

The page_menu template tag lets you pass in an optional parent page, and a menu template that will be used recursively for rendering children, eg where "page" is the current page:
{% load pages_tags %}
{% page_menu page "pages/menus/tree.html" %}

ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mezzanine-users/Fk2Nm6K6qho/VyePF5D6CXgJ

Comment: I guess this might be a little late though :)